# Lost all favicons in Chrome bookmarks bar after update

Tags: google-chrome, favicon

I recently updated Chrome to v54.0.2840.71m on Windows 7. After the update I lost all of the favicons on my bookmarks bar and in my bookmarks folders (bookmarks for several hundred sites). Even if I click on a link on the bookmarks bar the associated favicon is not restored . Is there any quick way of restoring them? (and by quick I mean by not having to re-visit several hundred websites!)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now that I'm logged in as *me* (those previous two comments from "user659393" were me as well), and now that I have my favicons working again...

Since the problem appeared to be connected to my Chrome user profile on this computer, and as my Chrome profile is linked to my Google account (where all the info is synced in Google's cloud), I opted for the "reload" option.

With Chrome running, I changed to a different Chrome user profile account, and made sure all other Chrome windows were closed.  Then opened the Chrome settings, went to the "People" section, selected the broken user account, and clicked "Remove...".

After that account was off of this computer, I added a person back in (I opted to use the same name and icon), and switched the browser to that user.  At that point, I had a basically "blank" account.  Going back to settings, I connected to my Google account (option at the top of the settings menu).

Once connected, all the bookmarks and extensions re-load, and the bookmarks all have the favicons again.

Best I can tell, the Chrome user profile became corrupt.  Restoring from the cloud (if you are setup to have your Chrome profile connected to a Google account) is a quick way to fix things.  It is also a great way to sync bookmarks and settings between multiple computers; this profile is shared between three computers this way... works great.

Pat

Answer (score 0):

I just lost my favicons (again) after updating Chrome. All I had to do was sign out of Chrome, close out of it, reopen it and sign back in and they were restored.

Answer (score 0):

A possible problem is that sync turned off. In Chrome, click you initial or avatar in the top right of the screen and if in the menu it says, "Turn sync on" it means that Google is running a different type of log in that is not synced to your Google account, and this is why the bookmarks and other important stuff like alternate log ins and stored passwords aren't working, Check "Turn sync on' and that might fix it.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. I find this answer unlikely because when it comes to syncing bookmarks, it's all or nothing. Either you have them it you don't, unlike the OP's problem of having them but just missing the favicons.